# Chrome Extension: set and change parameter in Url

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension which is able to set an url parameter, or change a parameter if it's already set at the end of the curent url of my website. This should be done in the backround. I'm not sure if this is possible.

I'd like to change url's like this

> ../bibliothek/Retrospect-of-Western-Travel
>
> ../bibliothek/Retrospect-of-Western-Travel?ref=kap-01

to this:

> http://www.lexikus.de/bibliothek/Retrospect-of-Western-Travel?ref=chrome

I think, first I have to set this permissions in my manifest.jason

```
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "*://*.google.com/"
  ],
```

I was not able make a working adaption of the script in this question:
[Is it possible to rewrite url (with extra parameters) with a Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256922/is-it-possible-to-rewrite-url-with-extra-parameters-with-chrome-extension)

But I think my question is a bit different. I hope you can help me. Thank you very much! Hajue

Comment: You need the `webRequestBlocking` permission as well. And a wildcard at the end, `*://*.google.com/*`, would not hurt either ;)

Comment: thank you very much @RobW - now it works with the permission "webRequest" in the manifest