# Chrome Extension: when being directed to a new page, replace assorted URL parameters with a different value before the URL request gets sent off

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

When I click I a link (or am getting redirected by a site), I want to replace the values of assorted tracking parameters in the requested URL with a different, universal value. For this example, let's use my username, so a link that directs to

```
www.abc.com/?utm_source=originalsource&utm_campaign=originalcampaign&cid=originalcid&gclid=originalgclid
```

would become `www.abc.com/?utm_source=WTTDOTM&utm_campaign=WTTDOTMcampaign&cid=WTTDOTM&gclid=WTTDOTM`

It’s important that these parameters get edited before the request is sent off, as the idea is to avoid the UTM/cid/gclid/etc tracking and leave a mark in the traffic data of whoever is looking at those tracking parameters. I know I have to use webRequest, and the logic seems pretty simple, but I don’t know how to find-and-replace in the URL on the fly with js. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256922/is-it-possible-to-rewrite-url-with-extra-parameters-with-a-chrome-extension) looks like its the closest to what I’m asking, but I don’t know how it would work with just modifying smaller slices of a URL as I'm pretty inexperienced with javascript and most of my coding knowledge is just slapping stuff together until it works.

To start with a simple sub-problem my question is: how can I use the webRequest API to replace `utm_campaign=***` in a URL with `utm_campaign=WTTDOTM` before the page is requested?

----EDIT:-----

@wOxxOm thank you for your helpful answer! I think I have the general structure down now, but I am still struggling with the formatting of regex rules, which I'm pretty unfamiliar with. The way I understand it, the rule `^(.*?utm_source=)(.+?(?=\\&)|$)(.*)` (and its "medium" variant) will capture all values before 'utm_source=' into group 1 and all values (or none in the case of it being the last parameter) after '&' into group 3 and then I should be able to make the regexSubstition group1+WTTDOTM+group3, right? When I currently try to upload the unpacked extension below, I get hit with an error that says "rules.json: Rule with id 1 specifies an incorrect value for the "regexFilter" key." I think I am just formatting it wrong, but I do not know what I need to fix. Can you help? Here are my rules.json and manifest.json files.

rules.json

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "regexSubstitution": "\\1WTTDOTM\\3"
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "^(.*?utm_source=)(.+?(?=\\&)|$)(.*)",
      "resourceTypes": [
        "main_frame"
      ]
    }
  },
{
    "id": 2,
    "priority": 2,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "regexSubstitution": "\\1WTTDOTM\\3"
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "^(.*?utm_medium=)(.+?(?=\\&)|$)(.*)",
      "resourceTypes": [
        "main_frame"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "WTTDOTM is a UTM",
    "version": "1.3",
    "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
    "<all_urls>"
],
    "description": "Replaces all UTM values with 'WTTDOTM'",
     "declarative_net_request" : {
    "rule_resources" : [{
      "id": "1",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "rules.json"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "rules.json"
    }],
    "icons": {
          "128": "icon128.png" }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) is the modern method, see the link for examples of using its regexFilter and regexSubstitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not *impossible* to do this with regular expressions but it's going to be frustrating. The text that you're trying to capture could contain almost anything, so building a regex that captures **what's after each query parameter and only what's after each query parameter** is going to be difficult. Instead I would suggest using Chrome's built in [URLSearchParams API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams#urlsearchparams_api).

Combined with Javascript's [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), what you're trying to do would probably look like this:

```js
const replaceTrackerParams = (urlString, replacementString) => {
  const url = new URL(urlString);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

  // If campagin parameters exist, replace them
  params.has('utm_source') && params.set('utm_source', replacementString)
  params.has('utm_campaign') && params.set('utm_campaign', replacementString)

  // Return modified URL
  return url.hostname + '?' + params.toString() 
}
```

Replace shorthand syntax with more complicated logic as needed.

Another answer suggested using declarativeNetRequest because it is the newer, more efficient API. This is true, but I don't think it supports callback functions yet.